# VirtualBox - how to get on the LAN on guest machine without bridged networking?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, virtualbox

I'm a Windows 8.1 user, every time I install Virtualbox with bridged networking support my PC won't wake up from sleep: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12063

The only fix I managed to find is to uninstall the bridged networking adapter.

I'm in a LAN, my router's IP is 192.168.1.1, I want the VirtualBox to get 192.168.1.x from my router's DHCP, how can I achieve this? I've been trying with NAT but I'm getting weird stuff like 10.0.0.5 or 192.168.1.56.1 and it doesn't seem to work properly (I have Ubuntu-vagrant-like install there and I have to access the project using the browser).

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second physical Network device NIC on your PC only for VirtualBox usage. Bridge the second NIC on virtual machine.